# Use pdf file as wallpaper

Tags: pdf, images, wallpaper

I have a series of high quality images stored as `pdf`, one image per file. I want to use these images as a a series of rotating wallpapers. However, apparently Ubuntu (16.04) does not handle pdf files as wallpaper (if I select the folder containing the pdf files in Desktop Settings, it shows empty). Is there a way to trick Ubuntu to make it think the file is an image? Or is the rendering of the background something quite different from the opening of a pdf file? (apparently, it is possible to use [video file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565154/how-to-set-a-mp4-as-a-wallpaper) and [gif files](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=73902) as wallpaper, so maybe this is also possible).

Notice that I am aware I could convert the pdf files to `png` or another image format (e.g. using `convert` tool), but **for the same quality the file grows around 10 times in size**. Therefore, I would rather keep the images in their current format.

Comment: `convert` is the wrong tool for that.  Try `pdfimages` first (this will extract images from raster PDFs), then if that doesn't work, try `pdftoppm` (this will render your PDF at a given resolution).  You can then convert the image to a smaller format.